# Fast restore of a Duplicati 2 backup

Tags: backup, restore, windows-backup, open-source, incremental-backup

I have started using [Duplicati 2](https://www.duplicati.com/) to backup my data to an external harddrive.

So far, it seems like a very robust and secure way to backup personal data, and it is opensource on top of all !

However I have noticed that restoring one or a few files from a big backup (more than 50 Gb) takes quite a long time : ~15 minutes.

It seems that in order to restore any number of files, it needs first to recreate the whole database (*i.e.* the "addresses" of all the backed-up files -more than 50 Gb- among the Duplicati backup blocks) and then downloads the few files that were requested, which is extremely time inefficient.

**This brings me to my question :**

- Is there any way to speed up the restoring process of a few files from a big Duplicati backup ?
- More precisely, is it possible to avoid recreating the whole database when trying to download only a small number of files from the backup ?

Comment: That's a big improvement on how long it [used to take](https://github.com/duplicati/duplicati/issues/1391). Yes, the database appears to be rebuilt if it doesn't exist on the computer doing the restore. I think this is a work in progress.